# How to get keys as well as values from sharedPreference file

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Whenever I try to get key and values from my sharedPreference file, I get only values like I have a key name "Anshuman" whose value is "Present".

But whenever I try my code I got only "Present". How can I get "Anshuman" too.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_date_detail_activity);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Date", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String,?> keys = sharedPreferences.getAll();

    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
        Toast.makeText(this,entry.getValue().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `entry. getKey ()` to get key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test this code :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Date", MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences .getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: thnx a lot brother :)